# Unable to access SharePoint Online site using SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have two different SharePoint Online tenancies.

1. Multi-factor authentication is enabled and it is using DUO authentication as well.
2. No multi-factor authentication

I have SharePoint Designer 2013 installed in my machine and I am able to access my "Tenancy 2" sites without any issue, but not "Tenancy 1". Tenancy 1 sites are throwing below error (Note: I have entered the right user name and password)

Is there any special configuration required to be able to access the SharePoint Online site with MFA and DUO enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an "app" password, or maybe a registry hack. See the following for info:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-2013-multifactor/bf47ba65-b252-43db-8421-dc7a7f155a15
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords
- A registry edit fix: https://www.christinawheeler365.com/?p=1849